# My php code is not inputting data to mySQL and giving me no feedback

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am not sure why my database is not receiving information from my website. Also, no error messages are popping up so I'm not sure the data is going anywhere at all. It appears to be letting me connect to the database, but when I click add employee I just get a blank page. Any suggestions?
EDIT: I have changed my code to only input one variable, but am still only returning a blank page.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Add New Record in MySQL Database</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php
         if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
            $dbhost = '';
            $dbuser = 'j';
            $dbpass = 'os';
            $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

            if(! $conn ) {
               die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
               $emp_name = addslashes ($_POST['employee_name']);

            } else {
               $emp_name = $_POST['employee_name'];
            }

            $sql = "INSERT INTO employee ". "(employee_name) ". "VALUES('$emp_name')";

            mysql_select_db('test_db');
            $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

            if(! $retval ) {
               die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            echo "Entered data successfully\n";

            mysql_close($conn);
         } else {
      ?>
            <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
               <table width = "400" border = "0" cellspacing = "1" cellpadding = "2">
                  <tr>
                     <td width = "100">
                        Employee Name
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <input name = "employee_name" type = "text" id = "employee_name">
                     </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                     <td width = "100"> 
                     </td>
                     <td> 
                     </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                     <td width = "100"> 
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <input name = "add" type = "submit" id = "add" value = "Add Employee">
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </form>
            <?php
         }
            ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are telling mysql you want to insert into one column and giving it two values. Mysql *must* be throwing an error for this.

Comment: @JohnConde I'm betting it's not even making it that far.

Comment: *"I just get a blank page"* => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Btw, I sure hope those aren't real login credentials.

Comment: Time to reset those credentials. Have you used `mysql_*` functions before perhaps they aren't available, see about error logs.

Comment: I have changed the line to " $sql = "INSERT INTO employee ". "(employee_name) ". "VALUES('$emp_name'"; ", but am still only receiving a blank page.

Comment: @JChase that is missing a closing `)`. Update the question. Also see answer below, and/or check for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO employee ". "(employee_name) ". "VALUES('$emp_name', NOW())";
```

You are passing 2 values in the sql, but only specifying one column. employee_name

you probably need to either remove the NOW() value or add another column (employee_name, date_added)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO employee ". "(employee_name) ". "VALUES('$emp_name')";

$sql = "INSERT INTO employee ". "(employee_name, date_added) ". "VALUES('$emp_name', NOW())";
```

Comment: I made this change, but am still only returning a blank page.

Comment: Have you got errors turned on for PHP? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: Yeah, nothing is popping up. I'm new to php so I'm really lost as to why this isn't working

Comment: if you type some random letters inside your <?php tags then run the script do you get an error message about a syntax error. or is it just a blank page. If it's still just a blank page then you need to turn errors on in your PHP set up. either in your php.ini, or at the top of your script <?php error_reporting(E_ALL);?>